# how to shorten a repetitive javascript php code

Tags: javascript, php, loops, repeat, shortcode

I am new to javascript. Please help with the following. I have a repetitive block of code that is about 40 "cases" of almost same code - which takes the returned value of wordpress do_shortcode and save to javascript variable (this part works fine).

I'd like to shorten it by some sort of a loop of code that achieved the same functionality. I try not to use COOKIE to pass value to PHP.
Please see sample 1st few lines:

```
switch (id) {
case 1: oh = `<?php echo do_shortcode("[block id=\"oh1\"]"); ?>`;break;
case 2: oh = `<?php echo do_shortcode("[block id=\"oh2\"]"); ?>`;break;
case 3: oh = `<?php echo do_shortcode("[block id=\"oh3\"]"); ?>`;break;
case 4: oh = `<?php echo do_shortcode("[block id=\"oh4\"]"); ?>`;break;`
...
}

jQuery('#id').html(oh);
```

I have to specify 40 lines like above and have not found another way. Please share your valuable idea. THANKS

Comment: what is the `switch` doing? just inserting a number in `case` of the number? you could insert the value of the variable directly wihout any `switch` statement (if there is no more inside).

Comment: please add some more of the code. actually it is not clear, what `do_shortcode` is doing.

Comment: do_shortcode is a wordpress function. In this case, it merely takes the content of HTML <div> block and return that content.

Comment: You should post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. If the solution is already posted consider accepting it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this (I assume your switch is in Javascript).

```
oh = '<?php echo do_shortcode("[block id=\"oh_num\"]"); ?>'.replace('_num', yourVariableInSwitch) ;break;`
```

In this case you don't even need switch statement.

If you have to do if 40 times:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    console.log('<?php echo do_shortcode("[block id=\"oh_num\"]"); ?>'.replace('_num', i);
}
```

---

Render switch case statements for javascript with PHP

```
switch (yourVariable) {
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 41; $i++) {
    print 'case ' . $i . ': oh = ' . do_shortcode("[block id=oh'" . $i . "']") . '; break;';
}
?>
}
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion. Error is: Block "oh1" not found. Even though there is a block named "oh1". What did i do wrong here?

Comment: Since you didn't specify that block as actually dependant, then we have to do it with PHP entirelly. I've updated an answer. @Kim

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 [string interpolation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)

```js
const myNumber = 2;
const oh = `<?php echo do_shortcode("[block id=\"oh${myNumber}\"]"); ?>`;
console.log(oh);
```

Comment: Good suggestion. But there is an error: Block "oh1516" not found. Even though the value of "myNumber" (above) is 1. Strange!!

Answer (score 0):

Do it all in PHP:

```
<?php
for($i=1,$l=41; $i<$l; $i++){
  echo "case $i: oh = ".do_shortcode("[block id='oh$i']").' break;'
}
?>
```

Comment: `for($i=1,$l=41; $i<$l; $i++)` vs `for($i=1; $i <= 41; $i++)`. What is cleaner?

Comment: You mean `$i <= 40`, but definitely the latter is clearer.

Comment: Well, the second is not the same as the first. I'm just storing the number to a variable. Maybe OP wants to replace `41` with `count($someArray)`, or something. Of course, I would use a `foreach` loop in that case.

Comment: but the $i value comes from javascript. I can pass its value to PHP via COOKIE. But then some user may not enable cookie!

Comment: Send AJAX to the Server and run your loop there.

Comment: IT WORKS!! THANK YOU